# addControl give a problem with ol.control.FullScreen

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm experiment some customizations of OpenLayers, when I try to use `map.addControl` with `ol.control.FullScreen` I see this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: t.element.setMap is not a function

This message cames from `PluggableMap.js`.

I do this:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
});

var fullScreen = new ol.control.FullScreen({className: 'ol-full-screen', tipLabel: 'Toggle full-screen'});
map.addControl(fullScreen);

var scaleLine = new ol.control.ScaleLine({className: 'ol-scale-line', target: document.getElementById('scale-line')});
map.addControl(scaleLine);

var view = new ol.View({
  center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([9.25040, 45.54318]),
  zoom: 2
});
map.setView(view);

var osm = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});
map.addLayer(osm);
```

If I comment `fullScreen` I can see whitout problems the map.

Comment: Code looks OK and for me exact copy works without problems, OL 6.2.1. Please post your full code on JSFiddle or similar site.

Comment: Here there is the complete code: https://gist.github.com/MaxDragonheart/9efd7b3d1761088e2a3e4c2f078d105c

Comment: I'm using OL 6.3.1 @TomazicM

Comment: It's not complete code, what's missing is `/static/css/general.css` and `/static/css/map.css`.

Comment: @TomazicM I've updated the gist. Some of styles is not used from this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some experimenting it seems this is a OL bug. The code from question works in IE11, Edge (new) and Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Luckily there is a workaround. If full screen control is added as a default map control, then it works also in Firefox.

Control is in this case added to the map like this:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([new ol.control.FullScreen()])
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay @TomazicM, I'm on holidays :)
Your solution is what I use normally. My aim now is to build my personal library and I would like to use the `addControl` function instead of the "classical" solution. This is a buf of OpenLayers or inside my code?

Comment: This has nothing to to with your code, it's OL bug.

Comment: Thank you. Then I give a feedback to the developers

Comment: Yes, I know @TomazicM but is more complicated use GIS SE and GitHub from the smartphone. :)
Aniway I've opened an isseu here: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/11450